# Set alias from sh script in ESXi 6

Tags: vmware-esxi, alias, sh

I have created a simple script to setup an alias on an ESXi 6.7 host:

```
#!/bin/sh
alias ll="ls -la"
echo "Profile done"
```

When I run the script I see the echo'd message on screen, but the alias is not set.   But if I execute the alias command from a command prompt it works fine.

Can someone explain how to setup an alias from a script?

Answer (score 3):

For me this works as expected.
Make sure that you dot source the script like this:

```
. ~/.profile
```

instead of executing it like this

```
~/.profile
```

The latter spawns a new shell process where the alias is created, but then terminates the spawned shell, leaving the original calling shell unmodified.

If you save your script as ~/.profile it will also get properly sourced when you log off and log in again.